# How do I know where the .data section needs to get the init data from? (gcc linker)

Tags: gcc, linker, microcontroller, bare-metal

When building a gcc based bare metal mcu project you need to take care of the initialization of the .data and .bss sections during startup.

The .bss section is quite easy since I just fill the entire section to 0.
But variables in the .data section needs to have their initialization data in rom/flash and copied during startup.

How do I know where the data with the initialization values can be found?

Let's take a example.

Let's say that I create two global variables in main.c

```
unsigned int my_global_variable_one  = 1;
unsigned int my_global_variable_two  = 2;
```

Then I can use objdump on the object file to see in what section they will be in, 
but I can't find anything in the objdump out put where the init data should be placed.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms main.o | grep my_global_variable
00000000 g     O .data  00000004 my_global_variable_one
00000004 g     O .data  00000004 my_global_variable_two
```

Then I can look at the resulting elf for the entire system, in this case main.elf.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-nm -n main.elf | grep my_global_variable
20000000 D my_global_variable_one
20000004 D my_global_variable_two
```

Where can I find where they are so I can do copy the data?
What do I need to put into my linker script?

It should be in something like .text or .rodata, but how do I know?

How can I check where the init data for my_global_variable_one is?

Can I find where this data is with any of the binutils commands like readelf or objdump?

/Thanks

---

This is on a stm32 (Cortex M3) mcu, and the CodeBench version of gcc is used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler puts all code and some read-only data in the `.text` section. There may also be a `.rodata` section. You can have your linker script put that in a ROM address something like this:

```
. = <rom-base-address>;
.rodata : { *(.rodata) }
<other read-only sections go here>
.text   : { *(.text) }
```

The compiler puts all the initial values of writable data in the `.data` section, and all symbols that don't have an initial value in `.bss`. The `.bss` is easy, you just place that in RAM. The `.data` wants to be in RAM at run time, but in ROM at load-time, and the linker script lets you do that with the `AT` keyword:

```
. = <ram-base-address>;
.bss  : { *(.bss) }
.data : AT ( ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text) )
        { *(.data) }
```

This means that the data section now has a different LMA and VMA (Load Memory Address / Virtual Memory Address). Your program will expect to find the data at the VMA (the run-time address) but the data will actually exist at the LMA (you may have to teach your flasher to do this), which is right after the `.text` section.

If you need to figure out where to copy to and from then you can create pointers in the linker script. So, modify the above example like this:

```
.data : AT ( ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text) )
        { _data_lma = LOADADDR(.data); _data_vma = .;
          *(.data);
          _data_size = SIZEOF (.data);}
```

You can then do `memcpy (_data_vma, _data_lma, _data_size)` in your start-up code (although you might have to hand-code that in assembler?) Those symbols will appear to your program as constant globals that resolve at link time. So, in your assembler code you might have something like:

```
_data_lma_k:
   .long _data_lma
```

Then the number will be hard coded into the `.text` section. Of course, the assembler syntax might be different on your platform.

For more information, see the linker manual [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html#Output-Section-LMA)

Comment: Well I noticed that the data is appended after the .text section, but you helped me get close enough :)